# REST Client Basic Authorization to a REST API

Tags: c#, rest, api, web-services, rest-client

I have a question. I have a Basic Authorization value that is Base64Encoded that looks something like this "aHZjYnN4NXJ4bXV6OmplWHN1Wl....", I am just wondering where I can put this value into the code? It is needed so I can receive the bearer access token. I get it to work in Postman, but not in this code. This code works to get JSON strings from other APIs that don't require the extra bit of authorization. But when I try it on another API that requires the Basic Authorization string, I get this error: {"errorMessage":["The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."],"errors":{}}. Couldn't find much documentation on the subject, any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the code in the form class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AuthtRestClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region UI Event Handlers
        private void CmdGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RestClient rClient = new RestClient();
            rClient.Endpoint = txtRequestURI.Text;

            rClient.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
            rClient.UserPassword = txtPassword.Text;

            DebugOutput("REst Client Created");

            string strResponse = string.Empty;

            strResponse = rClient.MakeRequest();

            DebugOutput(strResponse);
        }

        #endregion

        private void DebugOutput (string strDebugText)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(strDebugText + Environment.NewLine);
                txtResponse.Text = txtResponse.Text + strDebugText + Environment.NewLine;
                txtResponse.SelectionStart = txtResponse.TextLength;
                txtResponse.ScrollToCaret();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message, ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the RestClient class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace AuthtRestClient
{
    public enum HttpVerb
    {
        GET,
        POST,
        PUT,
        DELETE
    }

    public enum AuthenticationType
    {
        Basic,
        NTLM
    }

    public enum AuthenticationTechnique
    {
        RollYourOwn,
        NetworkCredential
    }

    class RestClient
    {
        public string Endpoint { get; set;  }
        public string EndPoint { get; }
        public HttpVerb HttpMethod { get; set;  }
        public AuthenticationType AuthType { get; set; }
        public AuthenticationTechnique AuthTech { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

        public RestClient()
        {
            EndPoint = string.Empty;
            HttpMethod = HttpVerb.GET;
        }

        public string MakeRequest()
        {
            string strResponseValue = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Endpoint);

            request.Method = HttpMethod.ToString();

            string authHeader = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UserName + ":" + UserPassword));
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authHeader);

            HttpWebResponse response = null;

            try 
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                // Process the response stream... (could be JSON, XML, HTML, etc...)

                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strResponseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }// End of StreamReader
                    }
                }// End of using ResponseStream

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                strResponseValue = "{\"errorMessage\":[\"" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\"],\"errors\":{}}";
            }
            finally
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    ((IDisposable)response).Dispose();
                }
            }

                return strResponseValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to pass it through several different ways, one of which looks like this, but have not been able to get it to work:

```
string authHeader = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("U4OXU5aHZjYnN4NXJ4bXV6ORIWUp==" + 
                ":" +UserName + ":" + UserPassword));
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + authHeader);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `(405) Method Not Allowed` indicates you're using the wrong verb (GET, POST, etc.) in your request.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using RestSharp.

```
// RestSharp code:
        var client = new RestClient("https://auth.example.com/oauthserver/oauth2/token/");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "1defca09-ab68-43cd-91a0-a78709a2fb41"); //this line not needed
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic U5aHZjYnN4NXJlWHN1WlhwZDZIbn==");
        request.AddParameter("undefined", "grant_type=client_credentials", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```